# What are performance implications of using `rec` keyword in Nix?

Tags: nix

What are performance implications of using `rec` keyword in Nix? E.g.

```
package = stdenv.mkDerivation rec {
  ...
}
```

Is it a good practice to remove `rec` when possible or Nix can do that automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference in performance is negligible; using `rec` to make an expression more readable is just fine. If you don't need `rec` however, then you shouldn't use it -- not so much because of performance considerations but because of readability. People who read your code expect the attribute set to be recursive when they see the `rec` keyword, so using it for non-recursive sets is confusing.